# How to execute Multiple result sets in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure with multiple select statements.

I am using the method below.

```
public function func_name(){
    $query = $this->db->query('CALL test()');
    return $query->result();
}
```

It is returning the first select statement results only.

How do I get results all off the select statements in my stored procedure.

Comment: Where is your stored procedure code ?

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
    NO SQL
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM users_data;
END

Comment: You are calling CALL proc_name(?,?) with 2 params where is that ?

Comment: yes, I edited my question, please see the changes.

Comment: Why are you not using a view or database table instead of a procedure?

Comment: That's not the answer. If there are more ways to make things easier, then why should not we use it.